# Network inspection of RMI or Corba web traffic over http?

Tags: java, debugging, networking, corba

I am looking for a tool that would assist me and other developers in debugging/inspecting the network traffic between a rich client application and a server where the communication protocol is either RMI/HTTP or Corba/HTTP.

I already have [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), which I LOVE, but it doesn't understand the payloads and just interprets them as octet-stream, hexadecimal garbage.

Either a stand alone program or an Eclipse plugin would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that very difficult in the case of RMI/JRMP, as it requires Java and the availability of all the application and library classes to deserialize the stream correctly. Without that the stream can't even be parsed.

In e case of IIOP I'm sure there are sniffers available, maybe even a Wireshark plugin.

Comment: I would have guessed in the case of RMI that I could at least determine the method name and paramter values...no?

Comment: No and no. The method name isn't passed, just a number, and the parameter values are serialized.